# Would time still exist after Heat Death of the Unverse?

Tags: cosmology, universe

From my (honestly limited) knowledge of what the Heat Death of the Universe is, I understand that HDotU is the point when energy levels across the entire Universe reach equillibrium, thus energy doesn't flow anymore absolutely anywhere, and thus nothing will ever happen anymore.

If that's the case, would time still be? Even when there's not a single event happening inside it and nobody's there to observe the ticking, does time (or space, come to think of it) exist? Or would HDotU cause something that ends the entire spacetime?

Comment: incorrect assumption, and no, time will still be there, just the arrow of time will be mostly absent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe

Comment: There is no "after." Thermodynamic equilibrium is something that is  approached asymptotically.

Comment: You could also look at the answer(s) to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460992/could-universe-expansion-continue-after-the-universe-reached-thermodynamic-equil.   A question that I have posed inspired by yours one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between time as a direction in spacetime and time as "something is happening".

When matter and energy equilibrate, what spacetime "sees" is just a (mostly) static distribution. The equations of general relativity still apply, and there will be an indefinite continuation of spacetime despite nothing really happening inside it.

From the perspective of time being discernable differences between states, time has ended. Not only are there no observers, but nothing that can store detected differences. There is no arrow of time, so going from state A to B is as likely as from B to A.

Note that this means that there will still be random thermal events, but they leave no long-term traces. So in the sense of time being "the state of the universe differs" there is time, but the states are macroscopically indistinguishable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem