# Could universe expansion continue after the universe reached thermodynamic equilibrium

Tags: cosmology, time

Stimulated by reading this question

[Would time still exist after Heat Death of the Unverse?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460888/would-time-still-exist-after-heat-death-of-the-unverse)

it seems that a literally eternal expansion is not precluded. This would be in accordance to a real cosmological constant that should persist on further pushing everything apart independent of equilibrium.

Is this correct at least according to the current cosmological view or even just plausible as hypothesis?

If yes, can one think of time as to exists for ever but also to a kind of persisting arrow of time (though there shouldn't be something happening in that direction except expansion itself).

Comment: You have to make the question clearer.Are you talking of the inflation period? where the equilibrium was reached? Have a look at this model of inflation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)

Comment: @anna v not. Thinking of a death by entropy scenario. It seems strange to think of a time arrow but an ongoing expansion could let to think even in absence of observer. In other words would be eternal dilution of energy/matter postpone indefinitely what is thought to be dead by heat? Though nothing locally will occur as homogeneity is already in place

Comment: Less than an hour after you asked the question, you accept the 1st answer given? How do you know that someone might not give a better answer? Once an answer is accepted, some people might be discouraged from answering.

Comment: I don't think that someone who knows a better answer would be discouraged. Anyway I reopen it just in case it is. About the how I do know. ... I don't. Just after a short discussion with a commenter I came to realised what the answer confirmed. I would not have ask a question anymore. It is even a bit silly as for I was supposing an after to a state that is asymptotically "reached". Actually I should signal this answer also to the question that inspired my own Q and I have linked. @D. Halsey.

Answer (score 1):

> Could universe expansion continue after the universe reached thermodynamic equilibrium?

Thermodynamic equilibrium is something that is approached asymptotically. There is no "after."

According to current models, the expansion of the universe will continue indefinitely.

> can one think of time as to exists for ever but also to a kind of persisting arrow of time (though there shouldn't be something happening in that direction except expansion itself).

Yes, I think it's true that we have an arrow of time due to cosmological expansion which is independent of the thermodynamic arrow of time. Both arrows of time will continue to exist indefinitely.

Comment: I just realised while answering to the comment of @anna v

Comment: "... we have an arrow of time due to cosmological expansion..." Are you saying that if the universe turns out to be finite & eventually starts contracting, then the arrow of time will reverse?

Comment: @D.Halsey: The arrow of time due to cosmological expansion is independent of the thermodynamic arrow. The thermodynamic arrow is the one that has consequences in everyday life and in laboratory experiments.

Comment: @D. Halsey. Just for clarity not to hinder a different discussion.  Scenario is that of a end by entropy (or death by heat), again as in the Q that originally inspired my one.